# PostgreSQL change field sequence

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

There was a problem copying some tables from one schema to another and now I have a few tables with serial fields pointing another schema's sequences. I want to change that dependency.

I need to copy those sequences to the table schema and change the field to point the copies in the current table schema.

Table 1 definition:

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.table1
(
    gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('schema2.table1_seq'::regclass),
    ...
)
```

I want it to point schema1.table1_seq . Is it posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ALTER TABLE:`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

```
ALTER TABLE schema1.table1 ALTER gid SET DEFAULT nextval('schema1.table1_seq'::regclass);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had tried that, but probably missing something. Yours work!!! (mark as correct as soon as I can)

Comment: If `schema1.table1_seq` doesn't exist yet, does this create a sequence for `gid` beginning at 1? If `schema1.table1` has `gid`s from 1 to 100, does this know to begin at `gid` 101? I think you'd need a `start with` clause like @VaoTsun suggests in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

it should be done itself while moving:

```
t=# create schema schema1;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# create table schema1.a(i serial);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create schema schema2;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# alter table schema1.a set schema schema2;
ALTER TABLE
t=# \d b.a
                               Table "schema2.a"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |            Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------
 i      | integer |           | not null | nextval('schema2.a_i_seq'::regclass)
```

but lets mock up your state:

```
t=# create sequence schema1.s;
CREATE SEQUENCE
t=# create table schema2.a(i int default nextval('schema1.s'::regclass));
CREATE TABLE
```

now you need:

```
t=# create sequence schema2.s start with 99;
CREATE SEQUENCE
t=# alter table schema2.a alter column i set default nextval('schema2.s'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE
```

with 99 to be actual number copied from `schema1.s`...